# find command does not find existing file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I create `starttime_file` and `endtime_file` hourly and the interval is 1 hour.

The purpose of this is to check the files which are created hourly.
But the thing is that I sometimes receive error code due to No such file or directory, although there is that file.
Could you let me know what would be the reason for this?

```
starttime_file
endtile_file
```

```
find ~/ -type -f -newer starttime_file -a ! -newer endtime_file > listfile.txt
```

When I conducted this on crontab hourly based, I received fail msg saying that no such file or directory which was created at Oct. 30th 16:15.

test200.txt was created at 16:15 and when I think, I need to take the error msg only once.

What would be the reason for this?

[image]

I really dunno what I need to try.
I suspected the authority issue but when I find this file on normal user status, I was able to find this file as well.

Both are working well on normal user status.

```
ll -rtl | grep -i "test200"
find ~/ -name "teset200.txt"
```

Comment: Showing evidence that the mtimes are what you think they are would help. Remember, these are _modification_ times, not _creation_ times (ctime isn't creation time either -- most UNIX filesystems don't track creation time at all).

Comment: oops, I am sorry. I mean last modification time. You are right. I want to list the files that are modified hourly.

Comment: Can you please try to copy verbatim the invocation you use? I see two problems with your `find` that make me think it would never have worked. Firstly, your first `newer` is missing the hyphen. Secondly the `!` won't work on the command line in any shell I use (varied versions of bash, occasionally zsh). That should be written as `-not` instead.

Comment: oh! I edited the hyphen. You mean find ~/ -type -f -newer starttime_file -not -newer endtime_file > listfile.txt ? I can use ! though...

Comment: @tink `-not` is not POSIX, `!` is. `!` is also bash history expansion, so it should be quoted (although history expansion is off by default in a non-interactive shell script). I'd recommend `\!` or `'!'`, although it's probably not the problem here.

Comment: Are you sure the right user is running the cron job? `listfile.txt` is always created, by the shell (before find runs, regardless of its errors), _unless_ user doesn't have write permission. This also effects how `~` is expanded. You can use `find ~user` to access `user`'s home dir from eg. a root cron job. Also consider if `test` is more useful than find: `test file1 -nt file2` (newer than), `help test`.

Comment: The weird thing is that the other files are well recored on the list but only this file has problem. I really dunno why.. and I think I should have this error once althouth this file has error because this code records the list of modified files hourly. The same error occured for 7 hours..

Comment: @dan , I want to list up all the files which were modified between when starttime_file was modified and when endtile_file was modified. In this case, if I use -nt it'd be quite complicated I think...I checked user as well.. I really dunno why...